# How to differentiate a QNetworkReply is aborted or not?

Tags: c++, qt, networking

I have the following code:

```
connect(&netMgr, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(loadFinished(QNetworkReply*)), Qt::UniqueConnection);
reply = netMgr.get(qheader);
```

How could I tell whether the loadFinished(); slot is triggered by calling
reply->abort() or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If aborted, `QNetworkReply::error()` should return `QNetworkReply::OperationCanceledError`, which means:

> the operation was canceled via calls to abort() or close() before it was finished.